# Plugin SortOrder

Tags: magento2, plugin, sorting, magento2.4.5

I was reading plugin documentation and I was wondering, if there is a plugin with SortOrder=0 how can i excute another plugin before that one, would SortOrder=-1 work? Is that a bad practice? Is there a better way to achieve that result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un plugin personalizado que se ejecute antes que un plugin original en Magento 2, con sortOrder=0, puedes seguir estos pasos:

Crea un archivo de configuración en tu módulo personalizado, llamado di.xml.

Agrega el siguiente código en el archivo di.xml para reordenar el plugin:

...
[image]
...

Reemplaza Original\Module\Class\Name con la clase original del módulo al que deseas aplicar el plugin.

Reemplaza Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomPluginName con la ruta completa de tu plugin personalizado.

Reemplaza CustomPluginName con el nombre de tu plugin personalizado.

Establece el sortOrder con un número negativo, en este caso usamos -1, para indicar que el plugin personalizado debe ejecutarse antes que el plugin original.

Guarda los cambios y actualiza tu sitio.

Verifica que tu plugin personalizado esté funcionando correctamente con el nuevo orden de prioridad establecido.

Recuerda que los números negativos tienen prioridad sobre los números positivos, es por eso que usar un número negativo en el sortOrder hará que tu plugin personalizado se ejecute antes del plugin original.

Usar un sortOrder negativo en un plugin personalizado en Magento 2 puede ser una buena práctica si deseas que tu plugin se ejecute antes que el plugin original. Sin embargo, hay algunas consideraciones a tener en cuenta al hacerlo.

Es importante tener en cuenta que los números negativos tienen prioridad sobre los números positivos en el sortOrder, por lo que tu plugin personalizado se ejecutará antes de cualquier plugin con un sortOrder positivo. Esto puede causar conflictos si hay otros plugins que dependen del plugin original o que también están configurados para ejecutarse antes del plugin original.

Es importante asegurarse de que tu plugin personalizado no esté causando problemas en el funcionamiento del plugin original. Si tu plugin personalizado modifica o altera el comportamiento del plugin original, puede causar problemas con otras funciones o extensiones que dependan de ese plugin.

Es recomendable siempre documentar las modificaciones realizadas en el plugin original y en el plugin personalizado.

En resumen, usar un sortOrder negativo puede ser una buena práctica si se usa con precaución y se tiene en cuenta las posibles consecuencias. Sin embargo, es importante considerar todas las posibles implicaciones antes de tomar la decisión de usar un sortOrder negativo.